Gitlab CI/CD pipeline running AWS CDK to deploy application: error duting bootstrap on missing permission
I'm working on a simple node-based AWS cloud app using CDK and running everything from my pc is totally fine, but now I'm trying to build a CI/CD pipeline and facing some issues during deploy.
gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
  - dependencies
  - cdk

default:
  image: node:20
  cache: &default-cache
    key:
      files:
        - package-lock.json
    paths:
      - node_modules/

download-dependencies:
  stage: dependencies
  script:
    - npm install

synth-and-deploy:
  stage: cdk
  environment:
    name: production
  script:
    - npm run cdk-bootstrap
    - npm run cdk-synth
    - npm run cdk-deploy

package.json
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "bin": {
    "app": "bin/app.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "echo \"The build step is not required when using JavaScript!\" && exit 0",
    "cdk": "cdk",
    "cdk-synth": "cdk synth",
    "cdk-deploy": "cdk deploy --asset-parallelism",
    "cdk-bootstrap": "cdk bootstrap",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "aws-cdk": "2.139.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-cdk-lib": "2.139.0",
    "constructs": "^10.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5"
  }
}

Pipeline error:
Sinthesizing and deployng within the pipeline gives following error but cannot understand why.
$ npm run cdk-bootstrap
> app@0.1.0 cdk-bootstrap
> cdk bootstrap
 ⏳  Bootstrapping environment aws://XXXXXXXXXXXX/eu-central-1...
Trusted accounts for deployment: (none)
Trusted accounts for lookup: (none)
Using default execution policy of 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess'. Pass '--cloudformation-execution-policies' to customize.
 ❌  Environment aws://XXXXXXXXXXXX/eu-central-1 failed bootstrapping: AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:user/personal is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:DescribeStacks on resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:stack/CDKToolkit/2d61076a-2a99-481b-a7af-59e9d3b30401 because no identity-based policy allows the cloudformation:DescribeStacks action
    at Request.extractError (/builds/aws4485044/auth/backend/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:385:46692)
    at Request.callListeners (/builds/aws4485044/auth/backend/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:385:91559)
    at Request.emit (/builds/aws4485044/auth/backend/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:385:91007)
    at Request.emit (/builds/aws4485044/auth/backend/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:385:199533)
    at Request.transition (/builds/aws4485044/auth/backend/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:385:193085)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/builds/aws4485044/auth/backend/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:385:157957)
    at /builds/aws4485044/auth/backend/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:385:158287
    at Request.<anonymous> (/builds/aws4485044/auth/backend/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:385:193377)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/builds/aws4485044/auth/backend/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:385:199608)
    at Request.callListeners (/builds/aws4485044/auth/backend/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:385:91727) {
  code: 'AccessDenied',
  time: 2024-11-15T16:40:43.142Z,
  requestId: '2d3e936f-8348-48bd-8304-da15c366c91e',
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 916.0680627857454
}
User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:user/personal is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:DescribeStacks on resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:stack/CDKToolkit/ because no identity-based policy allows the cloudformation:DescribeStacks action




How are you granting the gitlab runner access to AWS? FYI - you don't need to run bootstrapping on every deploy, it's a one-off sort of task.
